# Phantomjs / Node.js - Refactoring block of code

Tags: node.js, refactoring, phantomjs

I am writing a testing application, for the company where I work, using Node.js and Phantomjs. Right now, the relevant part of my code is something like this:

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
        ph.createPage(function (page) {
                page.set('viewportSize', { width: 1920, height: 1080 });
                page.set('settings.javascriptEnabled', true);
                page.set('settings.loadImages', true);
                page.set('settings.localToRemoteUrlAccess', true);
                page.set('settings.userAgent', userAgentStrings[randomInt(0, 5)]);
                page.set('settings.webSecurityEnabled', false);
                page.set('settings.resourceTimeout', 5000);

                page.open(URL, function (status) {
                        if (status == 'success') {
                                page.evaluate(function (result) {
                                        return document.title;
                                }, function (result) {
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                                log.info('Status: ', status);
                                                ph.exit();
                                        }, 60 * 1000);
                                });
                        } else if (status == 'fail') {
                                log.error('Status: ', status);
                                ph.exit();
                        }
                });
        });
});
```

My question is this: Is there a way to refactor my code in such a way that I can call the "page.open(..." function from outside the "phantom.create(..." block?

I plan to implement node-cron and have one block of code where I set up all the options for the page and another one that I will actually use to open the page. In the end, the opening part will be handled by node-cron, repeating ad infinitum.

Comment: The question is, why do you want to do this? Do you think that you save some resources because of this or do you think that you improve the response time? I think that you won't achieve either of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example on how to do this. You just need to store your phantom object somewhere and reuse it. Be aware that I made this simple so that you can reuse the concept but that you would need more error handling.

```
var jobRunner = function() {
  // The phantom object will be stored here
  this.ph;

  // The page object will be stored here
  this.page;
};

jobRunner.prototype.start = function(readyCallback) {
  var self = this;

  phantom.create(function (ph) {
    self.ph = ph;
    self.ph.createPage(function (page) {
      page.set('viewportSize', { width: 1920, height: 1080 });
      page.set('settings.javascriptEnabled', true);
      page.set('settings.loadImages', true);
      page.set('settings.localToRemoteUrlAccess', true);
      page.set('settings.userAgent', userAgentStrings[randomInt(0, 5)]);
      page.set('settings.webSecurityEnabled', false);
      page.set('settings.resourceTimeout', 5000);

      self.page = page;
      readyCallback();
    });
  });
};

jobRunner.prototype.doUrl = function(url) {
  var self = this;
  this.page.open(URL, function (status) {
    if (status == 'success') {
      page.evaluate(function (result) {
        return document.title;
      }, function (result) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          log.info('Status: ', status);
          self.ph.exit();
        }, 60 * 1000);
      });
    } else if (status == 'fail') {
      log.error('Status: ', status);
      self.ph.exit();
    }
  });
}

var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var phantomJob = new jobRunner();

// Wait for Phantom to be ready then start the Cron Job.
phantomJob.start(function() {
  var cron = new CronJob('*/5 * * * * *', function() {
    phantomJob.doUrl("http://yoururl.com");
  });
});
```

Comment: First things first, thank you for your excellent answer. Now, could you please elaborate as to what error handling I might implement? You seem like one I could use advice from.